# Flutter: Condition [FieldPath([type]), == type ] already exists in this query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code:

```
Query _cardsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Cards');

StreamSubscription _stream;

String _selectedType;


 // This method is called after in initState() method 
 void _getDataAndListen() {
   _stream?.cancel();
   _stream=_cardsQuery
          .orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
          .snapshots()
          .listen((collection) => _fillData(collection));
  }
```

It works fine

But when I add new `where` to the `_cardsQuery`:

```
// This method is called after selecting the _selectedType
void _preparingQueryAndReListen() {
    if (_selectedType != null) {
      _cardsQuery = _cardsQuery.where('type', isEqualTo: _selectedType);
    }
    _getDataAndListen();
  }
```

The following error appears :

> conditions .where((List item) => equality.equals(condition,
> item))
> .isEmpty': Condition [FieldPath([type]), ==, type] already exists in this query.

Where is the error in this code

Packages used in the code is : [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore)

**Any help, thank you**

Comment: From the error message it looks like you're adding the same condition twice to the query. I don't immediately see how that happens in the code though. Is there any other code modifying `_cardsQuery`?

Comment: It is the only code that modifies _cardsQuery, You have replaced _cardsQuery with FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection ('Cards'), It works, but I lost a check that the variable is null or not, What do I do, thank you

Comment: Note: The first time it does not give this error, but rather the second time and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're calling `_preparingQueryAndReListen` multiple times. Each time the code takes the existing `_cardsQuery` and adds a condition on `type`. Since a query can only contain one condition on each specific field, this call correctly fails after the first time.

A simple fix based on the code you shared is to rebuild the query from scratch each time `_preparingQueryAndReListen` is called:

```
  void _preparingQueryAndReListen() {
    _cardsQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Cards');
    if (_selectedType != null) {
      _cardsQuery = _cardsQuery.where('type', isEqualTo: _selectedType);
    }
    _getDataAndListen();
  }
```